# Set Entry ID & Member ID's higher

Tags: database

Hoping this is possible.

I want to set my entry_id and member_id numbers higher.  Meaning when the next entry is entered or a member joins it goes to the new higher # I set.  Right now my entry ID is at 271, I would like to put that at 1001 for the next entry ID entered.  Also do the same for members, not so high but at least 100. I tried (ALTER TABLE exp_channel_data AUTO_INCREMENT = 1001) but if simply kept the next number in line 272.

So can it be done, right now I have no members, I am just testing, I have a complete backup of everything.

Is it safe, is it possible without sending EE into a crash? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, and I think it's safe but as you are doing make sure you backup test and roll back if you get unextpected results. ([Is it safe???](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzw1_2b-I7A) lol)

You where almost rigth with what you did before, however `exp_channel_data` is not the indexed table for channel data, you want `exp_channel_titles`, these are your 2 queries :

```
ALTER TABLE `exp_channel_titles` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1001

ALTER TABLE `exp_members` AUTO_INCREMENT = 101
```

I did a quick test on my local sandbox and it seemed to work.

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner, this is the correct answer. It's db related, expression engine won't even know you altered your database auto increment index.